# Can the verb 'judge' collocate with 'of'?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, collocation

I saw this sentence in an essay:

> Children’s cognitive development is on the preoperational stage, so they cannot consider as logical and judge of dangerous events.

I would say "judge sth" or "judge sth on sth" but never heard of "judge of sth" (where *judge* is a verb and not a noun), so I looked up on some dictionaries and the internet but could not find reliable sources.

If this is a legit usage of *judge* **as a verb**, can you explain and give some examples?

And I also want to ask about the phrase “as logical” in the above sentence but that would be another question. But I don't mind if you also explain this :) I don't quite get it. Does it mean “as logical as adult” or simply “logically”, or is it wrong?

Comment: judge of character

Comment: What makes you think it can or cannot? What prior research of your own have you done to try to answer the question before asking here?

Comment: Frank: that's the _noun_ "judge", which is not what the question was about.

Comment: I don't know why two people have downvoted: this seems quite unwarranted, particularly since the answer to the question is "yes" (see my answer), but several people are insisting on answering "no" or answering a different question.

Comment: @ColinFine I downvoted because of the way the question was asked, with no context or indication of any prior research; not so much because of the actual question itself.

Comment: After the edit, I have now retracted my downvote and voted to reopen. (Incidentally, you are quite right that “they cannot consider as logical” is not grammatical. While _judge of_ does exist, as per Colin’s answer, I would put these two usages right next to each other as dead giveaways that the author of the essay is not a native English speaker.)

Answer (score 8):

To answer the question (as opposed to telling you about the noun, which you didn't ask about), yes the verb "judge" can be construed with *of*, but the OED describes it as "now somewhat rare". It gives examples from 1534 to 1999, of which the most recent is

> At the time of writing (1999) it is too early to judge of its [sc. the development's] ultimate impact on the Medway scene.

There is one fairly common literary idiom where it occurs: "Judge of my delight, when ...".

Comment: For a recent and more pop-culture reference (the only one I can think of, having never heard “Judge of my delight when…”), compare Michael Jackson’s song _Who Is It?_ (1991): “Don’t you judge of my composure ’cause I’m lying to myself…”.

Comment: Searching for it in Google gives a page of instances from Google books: it appears it is rather old fashioned. But it's what I immediately thought of.

Comment: Thanks Colin! As it is rare or old-fashioned, is it proper to use it in an essay? And for all those rare or old-fashioned expressions, are they proper to be used in formal writings? @Colin Fine

Comment: I'm sorry, @user85614, I might have misled you. My comment about old-fashioned was about the idiom "Judge of my delight": when I looked in google books, I couldn't find any recent examples. But as I said, the OED has an example of _judge of_ from 1999, and that was in normal prose. But in general it's impossible to answer your question. It depends on the style, the context, and what your assessors want. I once wrote an essay for my masters and used a word that was normal in the technical background I came from, but my tutor didn't know the word and said "What does this mean?"

Answer (score 0):

The noun "*judge*" can be collocated with *of*, as you can see from the answers further up. However, the verb *to judge* does not collocate with of.

Perhaps you can have a look at below link for the different collocations and phrases you can have with either the noun or the verb.

Online OXFORD Collocation Dictionary :

http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=judge